# python + django: unable to find module with Popen

Tags: python, django, subprocess, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I use subprocess.Popen in one of the my views:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'foo/bar.py')
subprocess.Popen(["python",path])
```

In my wsgi file, I have

```
import os
import sys

ppath = '/home/socialsense/ss/src'
if ppath not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(ppath)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ss.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and under `src` i have `ss`, my django project.

But when I check my log file, bar.py encountered an error, `ImportError: No module named ss.discovery.models`. Now it seems that the module `ss` itself is not in `sys.path` when using `Popen`...

anything i did wrongly here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only be in `sys.path` for the current Python instance. To get it for another, use the `env` argument to `Popen` with `os.pathsep`:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
subprocess.Popen(["python",path], env = {'PYTHONPATH': os.pathsep.join(sys.path)})
```

You should really look into the [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) for running multiple instances of Python.

Edit: @Graham pointed out in a comment that you might want to run this external script with a different version of Python than the one you're calling it from. That sounds unlikely to me, but if so, you'd need most of `PYTHONPATH` to be different for it to work, so you'd need to just add `/home/socialsense/ss/src`.

Comment: Strictly speaking your shouldn't add the whole of sys.path into PYTHONPATH just in case the WSGI application wasn't running with the default Python version but an alternate one. Ie. 'python' is Python 2.6 but mod_wsgi was compiled for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
 /home/socialsense/ss
```

to the python path as well .

Comment: For other problems he hasn't encountered yet. ;-)